# Rails 4 Can't verify CSRF token authenticity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, csrf

I have an array in my `show.html.erb` page and want to pass it from javascript to a method in the Controller using an Ajax request , But it gives me error `HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity` `Can't verify CSRF token authenticity` and i have no clue where to search

here my log:

```
Started PUT "/new_surveys/submit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-15 19:26:12 +0200
Processing by NewSurveysController#update as JSON
Parameters: {"arrays"=>["valueSelected"], "id"=>"submit", "new_survey"=>{}}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 15ms

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
```

---

here is a part of my route file that handle this part

```
resources :new_surveys
put "/new_surveys/submit", to: 'new_surveys#submit'
```

my controller , after searching most of the answers was just add `skip_before_filter` but it was there from the beginning and same error

```
class NewSurveysController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_new_survey, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :submit]
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:submit]

# GET /new_surveys
# GET /new_surveys.json
def index
  @new_surveys = NewSurvey.all
end

def submit
  data = params[:arrays]
  some code ..
end
```

---

here is my AJAX call in the javascript of the `show.html.erb` :

```
function create_ajax_request (url, data, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('PUT', url, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json'); // I want JSON 
  xhr.responseType = "json";
  xhr.addEventListener('load', function() {
    xhr.responseJSON =  xhr.response;
    console.log(xhr.responseJSON);
    callback(xhr.responseJSON,  xhr);
   });
  xhr.send( JSON.stringify(data) );
  return xhr;
}

function submit()
{
  var SelectedValue = [];
  var name = 0;
  var radios = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for(var i=0; i<radios.length; i++) {
    if(radios[i].checked)
  {
  var valueSelected = radios[i].value;
  window.alert(valueSelected);
  SelectedValue.push("valueSelected")
  }
}
  var url = ['http://' + location.host, 'new_surveys', 'submit'].join('/');
  var callback = function(responseJSON, xhr) {
}
   create_ajax_request(url, {arrays: SelectedValue}, callback);
}
```

---

**solved** in the comments below , just had to remove auto generated methods that was created by scaffolding that was creating objects for the show , update .. etc

Comment: do you have <%= csrf_meta_tags %> in your layout header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**solved**

just had to remove auto generated methods that was created by scaffolding that was creating objects for the show , update .. etc

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the header in your ajax request.

```
var metaTags = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');
for ( var i = 0; i < metaTags.length; i++) {
  if (metaTags[i].name === 'csrf-token') {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', metaTags[i].content);
  }
}
```

Using the ajax functionality via the jquery-rails gem will give you this for free :)

Comment: I'm using jquery-rails gem and still experience a similar problem.

Comment: Did you try setting the header? If you're creating your own ajax requests, you need to setup the header. jquery-rails handles it for you with `:remote => true` links & forms, but if you do your own ajax call you have to add it. You can of course simplify my above example by using jquery to grab the meta tag.